AWS Assume temporary IAM policy for authenticate RDS access with Terraform
I'm managing the database.
I am about to be able to access rds with iam authentication.
However, our organization is managed as one sso role, so we are trying to create an iam policy dynamically according to the users who have accessed the sso (login with their own google ID).
for example,
# WHEN user name is John, make readonly policy document

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy" {
  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["rds-db:connect"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:rds-db:ap-northeast-1:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:dbuser:${aws_db_instance.main.id}/read_only_user"]
  }
}

# WHEN user name is Mike, make admin policy document

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy" {
  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["rds-db:connect"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:rds-db:ap-northeast-1:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:dbuser:${aws_db_instance.main.id}/admin"]
  }
}

in my opinion
1. When logging in as sso or /ec2 session manager accesses, the Lambda function is executed to determine the user within the Lambda function? and pass the policy
2. When logging in as sso or accessing the /ec2 session manager, the user is only allowed to use the created database user
I thought like this, but is this possible?
Or is there a simpler way?
Now, I'm going to write the Lambda function, and I'm going to write the trigger part of the Lambda function in Terraform
I'm in a difficult situation because I couldn't find related solutions on google.
